# Deploy Worklight V6 project with apache tomcat 7 server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight v6.0, apache tomcat 7.0 and MySQL 5.5.24. I have created a sample application with android environment, and export whole project as war file. I have deployed using ant script below.

Ant-Script.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="install">
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
 <classpath>
  <pathelement location="C:/Program Files/IBM/Worklight_6/WorklightServer/worklight-ant.jar"/>
 </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="databases">
<configuredatabase kind="Worklight">
  <mysql database="WRKLGHT" server="{IP Address}" user="worklight" password="worklight">
    <dba user="root" password=""/>
    <client hostname="{IP Address}"/>        
  </mysql>
  <driverclasspath>
    <pathelement location="E:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar"/>
  </driverclasspath>
</configuredatabase>
<configuredatabase kind="WorklightReports">
  <mysql database="WLREPORT" server="{IP Address}" user="worklight" password="worklight">
    <dba user="root" password=""/>
    <client hostname="{IP Address}"/>        
  </mysql>
  <driverclasspath>
    <pathelement location="E:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar"/>
  </driverclasspath>
</configuredatabase>
</target>

<target name="install">
<configureapplicationserver shortcutsDir="/tmp/shortcuts">
  <project warfile="E:/war_files/TestApps.war"/>
  <!-- Here you can define values which override the 
       default values of Worklight configuration properties -->
  <property name="serverSessionTimeout" value="10"/> 
  <applicationserver>
    <tomcat installdir="E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.30"/>
  </applicationserver>
  <database kind="Worklight">
    <mysql database="WRKLGHT" server="{IP Address}" user="worklight" password="worklight"/>
    <driverclasspath>
      <pathelement location="E:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar"/>
    </driverclasspath>
  </database>
  <database kind="WorklightReports">
    <mysql database="WLREPORT" server="{IP Address}" user="worklight"  password="worklight"/>
    <driverclasspath>
      <pathelement location="E:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar"/>
    </driverclasspath>
  </database>
 </configureapplicationserver>
</target>  
</project>
```

After getting success with this script.

I tried this url "http://{IP Address}:8088/worklight/"

But I did not get any output. It shows Mobile Browser Simulator with no contents.
Help me out on this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow... if you had visited this URL you mention, you'd get an error(!). The correct URL to use in Worklight 6.0 is: `http://{ip-address}:8088/worklight/console`.

Only then would you get to Worklight Console, from which you can preview your application.

Also note that the default port in Worklight 6.0 is `10080`, so be sure you have updated related properties appropriately if you intend on using `8088` instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 10080 port is worklight development server(WS liberty server). I need to use apache tomcat 7 server.

Comment: That's fine. I'm just making you aware of it.